# What's the rank of this well founded relation?

Tags: ordinals, trees

**Definition** A tree is an ordered list of trees. (N.B these are finite objects and there is a very simple computable bijection of them with $\mathbb N$)

**Examples** [] and [[],[],[]] and [[[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[[]]]] but it's much better to think of them like this (can ignore the colors for now) [image]

I was wondering what is the rank of the lexicographic order on trees?

---

Formally, we will write a:b for a list of trees whose first element is r and rest is b (r is red in the diagram and b is blue)

$(h:t) <_T (h':t')$ when

- $h=h'$ and $t <_T t'$
- $h <_T h'$ and $t$,$'t$ can be anything (e.g. $t$ could be enormously large compared to $t'$)

and this relation is well founded (I claim)

---

It is clear that the rank is bigger than $\omega$ since you can embed the naturals into 0=[], 1=[[]], 2=[[[]]], 3=[[[[]]], ... just long chains.

You easily embed $\omega+1$ because $[[],n] <_T [[[]],[]]$ for $n$ corresponding to any natural number tree - but by a similar idea we easily embed $\omega^2$. It seems like the rank of this is large.

Note, this is the same as the relation on http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/02/the-hydra-game/ and I expect has smaller rank.

I am not very comfortable with these notions, so I want to get a rigorous proof in the end - but for now I don't even know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this relation is well founded? For clarity, let $\bot = []$, the empty list.

Consider the following sequence:

\begin{align}
T_0 &= \big[[\bot,\bot],\bot\big] \\
T_1 &= \big[\bot,T_0\big] = \Bigg[\bot,\bigg[[\bot,\bot],\bot\bigg]\Bigg]\\
&\ \vdots \\
T_k &= \big[\bot,T_{k-1}\big]
\end{align}

Assuming that $\bot <_T [\bot,\bot]$ (you haven't defined this case), we have
$$T_1 <_T T_0,$$
that is
$$\bot : T_0 <_T [\bot,\bot] : \bot,$$
hence
$$T_k <_T T_{k-1}$$
and we have an infinite strictly decreasing sequence.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: @user58512 I would recommend you to look at the Dershowitz-Manna ordering. It is for multisets, not trees, but from there you can gain a lot of intuition on how to construct well-founded relations.

Comment: @user58512 I extended your relation because its definition is incomplete, particularly there is no _base case_. In fact you cannot compare anything, the definition is recursive (each case relates to $<_T$) and it does not end – there is no _concrete_ case where you say that $T_1 <_T T_2$; I didn't check all the details, but it seems that $<_T$ could be just the empty relation. I have no idea what you think your relation is, but I think that maybe you should put more work in your question before wasting other people time.